# Django Admin shows my foreignkey to intermediary model as a text input

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In my models.py I have a intermediary model for a ManyToMany relation between model A and B. And MyModel has a ForeignKey to that intermediary model. When I register MyModel in admin.py the foreignKey shows as a text input:

[image: wrong text input]

I don't understand why it doesn't show the **default foreignKey widget.**

This is my models.py:

```py
# This is a intermediary model from another relations
class InterModel(models.Model):
    a = ...
    b = ...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    psv = models.ForeignKey('InterModel', related_name='mymodels')
```

In my admin.py:

```py
admin.site.register(models.MyModel)
```

I use Django 1.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try to register the other model as well in your admin?

Comment: Thank you @Alper . I only want a default ForeignKey widget in MyModel referencing InterModel, which allows me to search and select the InterModel instance to link. I don't need to edit any field on InterModel.

Comment: Registering the InterModel in admin.py was the solution! I didn't know that I would need to register a model which I onlly need to link (no need to edit their fields in a Edit View because their instances already exist on the database). Thank you @Alper !